# Testing react component within react router

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, react-router

I want to test react component:

```
export class IdentityPage extends React.Component<PageProps, State> {
    constructor(props: PageProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() { this.reload(this.props.routeParams.id); }
    render(){....}
}
```

which is used in react router like this:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
        <Route path="Identities">
            <Route path=":action/:id" component={IdentityPage} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

However, the test fails with:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

when I try to run:

```
let pageProps: PageProps = {
    params: {
        action: "view",
        id: "0"
    }
};
let instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement(IdentityPage, pageProps));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change pageProps to include routeParams:

```
let pageProps: PageProps = {
    params: { action: "view", id: "0" },
    routeParams: { action: "view", id: "0" },
};

let instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement(IdentityPage, pageProps));
```

In the page I was simply accessing `routeParams` instead of `params`

Answer (score 4):

If you use react-router v4, you can use `<MemoryRouter ...>` and wrap your component with the `<Route ...>` component.

[MemoryRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter) keeps the history of your “URL” in memory (does not read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser environments.

As example ([from react-router repository](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/b18b9dd418a12f3c175e71dece289ead22ef9a09/packages/react-router/modules/__tests__/Route-test.js#L81))

```
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/sushi/california' ]}>
  <Route path="/sushi/:roll" render={({ match }) => {
    return <div>{match.url}</div>
  }}/>
</MemoryRouter>
```

So in your case

```
let instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['view/0']}>
    <Route path=":action/:id" component={IdentityPage} />
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```